# Using a fetch within a for loop within several fetch requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch, for-of-loop

Ok guys, I am really stuck on what to do here to make sure that everything executes in order. It feels like im missing an await or something else really simple but I really cant seem to piece together why my return await doesnt just return AFTER all the other fetches are done.

```
async function generateData(region, user) {
    const apiKey = "APIKEY";
    let promises = [];
    let gameData = [];
    fetch("https://" + region + ".api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" + user + "?api_key=" + apiKey)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(user => {
        return fetch("https://" + region + ".api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/" + user.accountId + "?api_key=" + apiKey)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const matches = data.matches.slice(0, 10);
        for (let match of matches) {
            promises.push(fetch("https://" + region + ".api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matches/" + match.gameId + "?api_key=" + apiKey).then(response => response.json()).then(game => {
                return new Game(
                    game.teams[0].win,
                    "Win",
                    "Fail",
                    idFetch([game.participants[0].championId, game.participants[1].championId, game.participants[2].championId, game.participants[3].championId, game.participants[4].championId]),
                    idFetch([game.participants[5].championId, game.participants[6].championId, game.participants[7].championId, game.participants[8].championId, game.participants[9].championId])
                );
            }));
        }
    });
    return await Promise.all(promises).then(dataArray => {
        console.log(dataArray);
        return dataArray;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreter does not wait your fetch to end before returning result. Try to add `await` before `fetch...` on line 5. But actually its pretty hard to read, try to not mix async/await syntax with .then, will be easier for yourself to understand things =)